# Calculate Max IF in Excel with output either NULL or NUMBER

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I know I can use `MAX(IF(A:A=$F2,B:B))` to calculate a max formula with criteria. However, I want `B:B` to pull the max of an *integer* (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.) or return `NULL` if all available and/or relevant data is `NULL`. However, if I use `MAX(IF(A:A=$F2,B:B&"")`, I get **0** as the result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site, PamelaM! Can you please show us a sample of your data so that we can better understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to test whether the data is null or not before doing the MAX:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=$F2)*(B:B<>""))>0,MAX(IF(A:A=$F2,B:B)),"")
```

NOTES:

- This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.
- Array formulas should limit the ranges to the data set and not use full columns, it will slow it down.  I used full columns to mimic what the OP provided, but is not good practice.